# $EY$ in a linear regression

Tags: regression, expected-value

Let $y=x^T\beta+e$ be a linear regresion with $e$~ $N(0,I\sigma^2)$ What can we say about the expected value of $y$ $(EY)$? Is it correct $EY=x^T\beta$?

Comment: If $x$ is nonstochastic, $E[y]=x^T\beta$. If $x$ is stochastic, then $E[y\mid x]=x^T\beta$.

Comment: Do you consider $x$ to be fixed or random?  If fixed, then your conclusion is an application of the linearity of expectation.